# make rigid body object the same shape as my model

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I have an anvil falling into a tower of blocks, however the blocks interact with the anvil before the models are actually touching. Can I make the rigid body object the same exact shape as my model?[image]
edit
After trying the first suggestion below, my anvil now just falls through the tower

Comment: In the collision tab menu you can see option "Shape" Try to change "convex hull" to "mesh", if it still won't work, check your blocks if they have shape box as well

Comment: yes, as MikoCG says, "Mesh" makes the collision shape exactly the same as your mesh.  It's a  lot less efficient so in general you should try to avoid using "Mesh" collision wherever possible.

Comment: Yes it is good to avoid but for shape like this it is basically impossible to use anything else if he want precise collision in all possible bents of that anvil (let's hope that anvil is lowpoly)

Comment: errm, not quite; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2D4PN7WO-4o

Comment: also it is a low poly anvil :D